# Find the number of spaces in a string

Tags: string, r

How can I create different columns on the basis of space, eg: "I am going Out"

```
ANs 3
Column1 Column2 Column3 Column14 
I          am     going    out
```

Comment: Perhaps you want `read.fwf` though I'm not sure what you're after.

Answer (score 17):

If you want the actual column values, as your example seems to indicate, then you can read a table from a text connection:

```
> read.table(textConnection("I am going Out"))
  V1 V2    V3  V4
1  I am going Out
```

To answer the title of your question, i.e. *how many* spaces there are, you can use `ncol` to count the columns of the above, and subtract one. However, if you are *only* interested in the number of spaces, the following is more efficient:

```
length(gregexpr(" ", "I am going Out")[[1]])
```

This uses a regular expression to search for the spaces.

The `[[1]]` takes the first element of the resulting list, which corresponds to the first item of the input vector with "I am going Out" as its only element. If you passed a different vector there, your list might have more than one element, or none at all for an empty vector.

If there is no space, `gregexpr` will still return a list of length `1`, with `-1` as the position of the match to indicate that there was no match. This causes the above code to incorrectly report one result in that case. A more elaborate solution, which deals with that and also accepts vectors as input, is the following:

```
countSpaces <- function(s) { sapply(gregexpr(" ", s), function(p) { sum(p>=0) } ) }
```

The function works as follows: `gregexpr` will return a *list* of results, one for each element of the input *vector* `s`. `sapply` will iterate over that list, and for each element of the list, compute the number of matches. Instead of counting the `length` of the vector of matched positions, it uses `sum` to only count the non-negative values, thus dropping any `-1` caused by a failed match. There is an implicit conversion from `FALSE/TRUE` to `0/1` happening in that sum. The result of `sapply` will again be a vector, and thus nicely match the input vector.

This function can be used to rewrite a data frame, as requested in [one comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12403312/find-the-number-of-spaces-in-a-string/12403370#comment16784356_12403370). So assuming you have a data frame called `foo` which has strings in column `bar` and should be modified to contain these counts in a new column `baz`. You can write this as

```
foo <- transform(foo, baz = countSpaces(bar))
```

Comment: +1. Depending on what they want though, this *might* be more appropriate: `length(gregexpr("[ ]+", "I    am going out")[[1]])` (answer = 3). With that phrase, (with extra spaces), the method you've used counts *each* space.

Comment: Hmm. How do you add multiple spaces in comments?

Comment: @mrdwab, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/30020/multiple-spaces-in-code-in-comments-get-merged-into-one. Workaround: use Non-break space, entered as a U+00A0 unicode codepoint.

Comment: how can i run this code on dataframe and get this function results in a new column in same dataset. Thanks!!

Comment: Hey i tried this code and seems we are getting same results for the entries with one space or no space  Ex: mike waugh result = 1 and also mike result = 1................any solution to that problem

Comment: @geniusakii, adjusted my answer in response to your two comments.

Answer (score 5):

Another way is to use the `strsplit` function:

```
R> strsplit("I am going Out", " ")[[1]]
[1] "I"     "am"    "going" "Out"
```

So we split the first argument - `I am going Out` - by the second argument - the empty space. Then we can just use `length`:

```
R> length(strsplit("I am going Out", " ")[[1]])
[1] 4
```

Comment: But we don't want to know the number of words. So I think MvG's answer is more appropriate.

Comment: I agree that @MvG's answer is better, but I don't follow your comment on "We don't know the number of words"

Comment: Well, we want to know the number of _spaces_ and not the number of _words_. You calculate the number of words.

Comment: @rinni Very good, correct point. I suspect that the OP wants to know the number of words - but I'm only guessing here.

Answer (score 5):

You can also use `str_count` from the `stringr` package. These are less verbose, and avoiding regexes can be a bit faster.

```
library(stringr)
text = "I am going Out"
#matches regular expression
str_count(text, ' ')
```

Or, if you want something faster

```
#matches literal text
str_count(text, fixed(' '))
```

Answer (score 4):

I must admit I haven't read really that carefully so this may not be what you're after but a possibility is..

```
x <- "I am going Out"
nchar(x)- nchar(gsub(" ", "", x))
```

An alternative to MvG's original suggestion (though less pretty):

```
as.data.frame(matrix(unlist(strsplit("I am   going Out", "\\s+", perl=TRUE)), nrow=1))
```